# Many mat-paginator instaces in *ngFor directive

Tags: angular, angular-material

So I got the following markup

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let portal of portalItems">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input ([ngModel])="getCategoryLabelDetails(portal.id).query" />
    </mat-form-field>
    <div *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{ item.name }}
    </div>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,25,50,100]"
                      [length]="getCategoryLabelDetails(portal.id).resultsLength"
                      [pageIndex]="getCategoryLabelDetails(portal.id).page"
                      [pageSize]="getCategoryLabelDetails(portal.id).perPage" [showFirstLastButtons]="true"
                      (page)="pageChangeEvent($event, portal)">
    </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

.ts

```
export interface PortalOptions {
    portalId: number;
    data: Category[];
    page: number;
    query: string;
    isPanelExpanded: boolean;
    loading: boolean;
    perPage: number;
    resultsLength: number;  
}    

getCategoryLabelDetails(portalId: number): PortalOptions {
    return this.categoryLabelOptions.find((optionItem: PortalOptions) => optionItem.portalId === portalId);
}
```

I can not change paginator page programmatically, previously I was doing it by `@ViewChild`selector eg.

```
@ViewChild('matPaginator') paginator: MatPaginator;

exampleMethod(page: number) {
    this.paginator.pageIndex = page;
}
```

but in this case i got x mat-paginator instances so I cant use `@ViewChild` there.

I also tried to pass `paginator` object into my search function

.html

```
<mat-paginator #paginator></mat-paginator>

 <mat-form-field>
     <input ([ngModel])="getCategoryLabelDetails(portal.id).query" (ngModelChange)="search($event, paginator)" />
 </mat-form-field>
```

.ts

```
search(event, paginator) {
    // paginator is undefined there
    paginator.pageIndex = 0;
}
```

Summarizing:
How I can access `mat-paginator` instace from e.g. first loop of *ngFor?

first instace is `pageIndex = 5`, second is `pageIndex = 4`, and change these values programmatically to first instace `pageIndex = 2` and second `pageIndex = 7`.

Solved:
Just create component that will take care of the ngFor loop content, e.g:

```
<div *ngFor="let portal of portalItems">
    <m-example-list [portalItem]="portal"></m-example-list>
</div>
```

So inside component I can use `ViewChild` to modify paginator `pageIndex`. Because now I got one paginator instance per component.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MaihanNijat added summary

Answer (score 1):

You have many instances of `mat-paginator`. Use `@ViewChildren` instead of `@ViewChild` to get reference to the components.

In the TS:

```
@ViewChildren(MatPaginator) paginators !: QueryList<MatPaginator>;
```

Refere to official documentation for more details: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

Comment: I tried this, but how `@ViewChildren` knows which of paginators is from specific loop in *ngFor? How can I access specific paginator and change his pageIndex?

Comment: @kuklyy since you have already tried. Aren't they in order? paginator in index 0 is the first loop... and so on?

Comment: They are dynamically rendered based on request from server. So when page loaded I got none paginators, when I load a list i got first response and then first paginator loads. So order there could change. Now im trying to play around specific id on `mat-paginator` element. E.g. `<mat-paginator id="paginatorOf{{portal.id}}">` but I don't think I can access this id from `ViewChildren`. Anyway I need relation like this. One paginator per one response from server (my portal object)